# Django/python : How to assign the ForeignKey field for the child model in Django views?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, foreign-keys, django-views

I have created a Child Model connected to the Parent Model via ForeignKey. When i tried to create a Child instance it returns nothing. I am not sure in my views child.Parent is working properly or not. I would appreciate helping me solve this.

Here's my code:

models.py:

```
Parent(models.Model):
    Parent = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("parents:detail", kwargs={"id": self.id})

Child(models.Model):
    Parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='children')
    Child = models.CharField(max_length=30)        

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

forms.py:

```
ChildForm(models.ModelForm):
    Parent = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = ["Parent", "Child",
        ]
```

views.py:

```
def child_create(request, id):
    parent_instance = get_object_or_404(Parent, id=id)
    form = ChildForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        child = form.save(commit=False)
        child.Parent = form.cleaned_data.get('parent_id')
        child.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(parent_instance.get_absolute_url())
    context = { 'form':form, 'parent_instance':parent_instance,}

    return render(request, "child_create.html", context)
```

templates/child_create.html:

```
{{if parent_instance.id}}
<form class="nomargin" method='POST' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}

        <input type='hidden' name='parent_id' value='{{ parent_instance.id }}' />
        <input type='submit'  value='Add a Child' class='btn btn-default' />
    </form>

{% endif %}
```

Comment: `child.Parent = form.cleaned_data.get('parent_id')` should be `child.Parent = parent_instance`

Comment: Thanks dude, A small mistake!!

Answer (score 0):

Use ModelChoiceField instead of CharField

forms.py:

```
ChildForm(models.ModelForm):
    Parent = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Parent.objects.all(), 
                                      widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = ["Parent", "Child",]
```

views.py:

```
def child_create(request, id):
    parent_instance = get_object_or_404(Parent, id=id)
    form = ChildForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        child = form.save(commit=False)
        child.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(parent_instance.get_absolute_url())
    context = { 'form':form, 'parent_instance':parent_instance,}

    return render(request, "child_create.html", context)
```

templates/child_create.html:

```
{{if parent_instance.id}}
<form class="nomargin" method='POST' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form|crispy }}

    <input type='hidden' name='Parent' value='{{ parent_instance.pk }}' />
    <input type='submit'  value='Add a Child' class='btn btn-default' />
</form>
{% endif %}
```